# fastest data structure to find the superstring of a string?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, data-structures

I have a huge vocabulary and want to find all words in the vocabulary that contain the given string. that means I want to find all superstring of a given string among whole vocabulary. However Tree data structure is good for contains() query, and there exist some algorithm to find substrings, but I couldn't find any algorithm to solve this.

I want to use this algorithm ( or data structure )  in Java.

Comment: This sounds like the stemming problem you find in natural language processing.  There are existing, optimized stemmers out there.  If you want to write your own, have a look at source code for open source stemmers for inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

The idea is, given a string, every prefix of some suffix of this string, is a substring of that string (and every substring is a prefix of some suffix).

This means, you can create a suffix tree of the words, where the "leaf" of each suffix points to the original string.

Now, searching for a substring, you need to traverse the tree by following the nodes of the input substring, and then do some kind of tree traversal (like [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)), to find all reachable leaves. Each such leaf will be a suffix of some string, which the query string is a substring of.

This solution is pretty cheap, it is linear in the size of the output and size of query.